# problem after install of an extension: Mage registry key "_singleton/aw_layerednavigation/observer" already exists

Tags: extensions, singleton

After intalling this extension, I can not acess to the front-end or admin..

I'm having this error:

```
    Mage registry key "_singleton/aw_layerednavigation/observer" already exists
Trace:
    #0 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/DISTRIBUTION/app/Mage.php(223): Mage::throwException('Mage registry k...')
    #1 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/DISTRIBUTION/app/Mage.php(481): Mage::register('_singleton/aw_l...', false)
    #2 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/DISTRIBUTION/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1335): Mage::getSingleton('aw_layerednavig...')
    #3 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/DISTRIBUTION/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
    #4 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/DISTRIBUTION/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(384): Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_acti...')
    #5 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/DISTRIBUTION/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(137): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
    #6 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/DISTRIBUTION/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'b-responsive-ho...')
    #7 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/DISTRIBUTION/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'b-responsive-ho...')
    #8 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/DISTRIBUTION/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction()
    #9 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/DISTRIBUTION/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
    #10 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/DISTRIBUTION/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
    #11 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/DISTRIBUTION/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
    #12 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/DISTRIBUTION/app/Mage.php(688): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
    #13 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/distribution/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
    #14 {main}
```

This is the path I've been following for this extension ....

http://confluence.aheadworks.com/display/EUDOC/Layered+Navigation#LayeredNavigation-Installation

I've using the b-responsive theme,i took care to delete the cache manually and Disable the Compilation . ..

I really don't know what can i do . .. I'm stuck on this for the two last days .. .

this is the confix.xml of the plugin if it helps .. I can't really see anything wrong( I mean, not the full cod,e just the section related to singleton)

```
<events>
    <controller_front_init_before>
        <observers>
            <aw_layerednavigation_controller_front_init_before>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>aw_layerednavigation/observer</class>
                <method>controllerFrontInitBefore</method>
            </aw_layerednavigation_controller_front_init_before>
        </observers>
    </controller_front_init_before>
    <controller_action_layout_render_before>
        <observers>
            <aw_layerednavigation_layout_render_before>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>aw_layerednavigation/observer</class>
                <method>beforeRenderLayout</method>
            </aw_layerednavigation_layout_render_before>
        </observers>
    </controller_action_layout_render_before>
</events>
```

Any help would be  .. just incredible !!

Thank you for your time !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, clear the cache.
If that didn't work, it means that for some reason `Mage::getModel('aw_layerednavigation/observer')` returns false.

Either the tag for models in your config.xml is not `aw_layerednavigation` or the file `Aw/LayeredNavigation/Model/Observer.php` does not exist or is not readable.

Comment: awesome - i was thinking some file in fact . . . . . . thank you :)